# What's wrong with below mysql query

Tags: mysql, sails.js, sails-mssqlserver

i have below query which i want to use in my application using nodejs i ran this query in mysql works fine but when i am running this query in application it's giving below error. Any help would be appreciated.

`SELECT COUNT(*) as nos, t.* FROM`stream`s,`track`t WHERE s.type = 1 AND s.createdAt <= 2018-07-01' AND s.createdAt >= '2018-06-01' AND t.type = 'audio' AND s.track = t.id GROUP BY s.track Order BY nos DESC, createdAt DESC LIMIT 50`

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
>    { Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' AND s.createdAt >= '2018-06-01' AND t.type = 'audio' AND s.track = t.id GROUP ' at line 1

Comment: are you missing an opening quote there?

Answer (score 2):

you are missing and opening quote:

```
.. AND s.createdAt <= 2018-07-01' ..
```

should be:

```
 ... AND s.createdAt <= '2018-07-01' ...
                       ^^^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

put a ' before "2018-07-01"

SELECT COUNT(*) as nos, t.* FROMstreams,trackt WHERE s.type = 1 AND s.createdAt <= '2018-07-01' AND s.createdAt >= '2018-06-01' AND t.type = 'audio' AND s.track = t.id GROUP BY s.track Order BY nos DESC, createdAt DESC LIMIT 50